# how to add minutes and hours to countdown360 timer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

JS timer only works with seconds, how to add minutes and hours?
I am using https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360 countdown timer
[image: I want to show as in image]

```
> Its official page shows only for seconds http://jsfiddle.net/johnschult/gs3WY/
```

Answer (score 1):

The description on the site describes this as "A simple countdown timer in seconds", so there is no option to change to minutes

But there are other countdown timers that are more configurable.  See, for example,any listed here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=countdown+timer

If you want to use the countdown timer that you mentioned, you're going to have to do some modification to the source code.  For starters, replace all 37 references of "seconds" to "minutes" and then edit any of the math to convert times to minutes.

If would be great if you could submit your changes as a pull request to the original author too.

Comment: well you are correct I used [Timecircles](https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles) Jquery plugin it worked for me plus 1  for this

Comment: Great!  Glad you found something and that looks like it fits your needs.  Can you mark my answer as the accepted one so I get full points?

Comment: Thanks for your help but my question was to add minutes and hour to countdown360 timer if you can help me to use the same plugin I will surely mark this as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a plugin and not implementing the timer by yourself, you cannot change its settings - it is a timer only for seconds. 
What you can do is look for a timer that has more capacity, like [this one](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) I found.